# Calling JavaScript function ping() in onClick of an HTML hyperlink tag results in TypeError

Tags: javascript, html

I stumbled upon this today and since I'm no browser guru or a web developer, it's possible I missed something rather obvious. Observe the simple HTML below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function ping() {
            console.log('pong');
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onClick="ping()">Call ping</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I expected when clicking on the link is to have pong printed in the console. However, what I get in both Chrome and Firefox is "TypeError: ping is not a function". If I call the function directly from the console, it works. If I rename the ping function to anything else, it works. If I replace the "a" tag with, say, "button" tag, whilst leaving the function called ping, it works!

It seems that somehow, only in this specific combination: onClick of tag "a" with function called ping() results in the above error. Am I crazy or did I just discover the most insignificant bug in the world? If it is a bug, I find it very strange that it happens in both Chrome and Firefox, since they have different JavaScript engine implementation, different layout engine implementation etc.

Comment: `onClick="ping()"`  should be `onclick=ping()`

Comment: I think `ping` is a reserved word. Try to rename your function.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak actually `onClick="ping()"` is more correct in terms of (x)html validation. and `onclick="ping()"` is even more correct than both as everything is small letters.

Comment: @putvande I first thought of that, but why does it work when called from within onClick of a button for example? Or, why does it not work when I just call ping from the console? What's the scope of it if it is a reserved keyword? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @putvande It's not a reserved word according to the language specification, and I couldn't find any references to it in the browser environment. However, you're right, something is forbidding the use of ping as a function name. Changing the name does make it work. http://jsbin.com/aDOYoGo/1/edit

Comment: @DhavalMarthak It doesn't work with all lowercase either. Try it out

Comment: @vlad what do you mean with _when called from within onClick of a button_?

Comment: More weirdness: it just doesn't work on an anchor. If you call ping directly from the script block, or from the onclick of e.g. a span, it does work. http://jsbin.com/ebiRuc/1/edit

Comment: @bfavaretto Try also changing the tag, that also makes it work. As I've said in the post, I tried that too and it seems that only this specific combination doesn't work. Weird, huh?

Comment: @putvande I meant, just try to change the tag to some other tag, like button or input and the call to ping() in onClick will work, without any other change.

Comment: Very strange, try `<a href="javascript:ping();">Call ping</a>` for example, that works. It has something to do with the `href` in the a tag.

Comment: @putvande Well, that's a different thing then. I don't think it's related to href being there per se. Try this, href removed, still the same behaviour on click:
    <a onclick="ping()">Call ping</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Some tests](http://jsbin.com/aDOYoGo/3/edit) I did show that inline event handlers have access to the element's attributes directly by name. So this happens if your function matches any valid attribute name (and `ping` [seems to be](http://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/text-level-semantics.html#dom-a-ping) a valid attribute in HTML5).

So your code is being interpreted as an attempt to issue a function call on `""` (the value of `ping`), and fails. That only happens with inline event handlers, not if you use `element.onclick=function(){...` or `addEventListener`, so the problem can be avoided if you use one of those methods (they are recommended anyway, as inline handlers violate the principle of [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide a more detailed explanation; I'll try to find some canonical references about this on the HTML and DOM specs.

Comment: Interesting insight about the inline event handlers, this seems to be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Added Attribute Ping**

> New ping attribute can be specified on a and area elements.
>
> Issue: There are various methods for tracking clickthroughs on a link
>   for advertising or QA purposes. Many of which involve executing a
>   script (client-side or server-side) to perform tracking before
>   following a link. This obscures the destination of the link to the end
>   user, forces the UA to follow HTTP redirects before reaching the
>   destination, and/or requires Javascript to follow a hyperlink.

[Read more at w3.org](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/AddedAttributePing)

so i guess that has something to do with.. ping being a string..

`<a href="#" onclick="alert(typeof ping)">Call ping</a>` alerts string... :/

Answer (score 0):

Please try following, `onclick` should be all small.

```
<a href="#" onclick="ping()">Call ping</a>
```

Cheers !!

Comment: I am. Did you try it out yourself?